# Get a Monotouch.Dialog InputElement for a password field

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to get the value from an EntryElement

```
    var password = new EntryElement("Password","Password",null,true);
```

I have a StyledStringElement with a click event like

```
    new Section()
                    {
                        new StyledStringElement ("Login", delegate {
                        Console.Write (string.Format("Password is {0}",password.Value));
                        Console.Write (string.Format("Email is {0}",email.Value));
                    })
```

When I click on the element I can see the email string value however the password is always null.

What do I need to do differently to get the password value?

Comment: make sure you have pressed return on the iPhone keyboard, if not the value will not saved

Comment: Doh! I feel silling. If you change your comment to the answer I can mark it as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: You can call password.FetchValue (); as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have pressed return on the iPhone keyboard, if not the value will not saved